# How to convert string to bitset?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

is there any possibility of converting string like '1101' to its BIT(4) equivalent in MySQL? I have checked CONVERT/CAST functions but they do not allow to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`CONV()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv)

```
CONV('1100', 2, 10) * 1
```

or [Bit-Field Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-field-literals.html)

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (bit_value BIT(4));

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (CONV('1100', 2, 10) * 1);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (b'1101');

SELECT bit_value, 
       BIN(bit_value) bin_representation
  FROM Table1
```

Output:

```
| BIT_VALUE | BIN_REPRESENTATION |
----------------------------------
|        12 |               1100 |
|        13 |               1101 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13db2/2)** demo